# GCC compile warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘enum month *’ [-Wformat]

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I get the following warning when I try to compile the code:

program141.c:13:5: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘enum month *’ [-Wformat]

```
// Program to print the number of days in a month

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    enum month { january = 1, february, march, april, may, june,
         july, august, september, october, november, december };
    enum month aMonth;
    int        days;

    printf ("Enter month number: ");
    scanf ("%i", &aMonth);

    switch (aMonth) {
    case january:
    case march:
    case may:
    case july:
    case august:
    case october:
    case december:
        days = 31;
        break;
    case april:
    case june:
    case september:
    case november:
        days = 30;
        break;
    case february:
        days = 28;
        break;
    default:
        printf ("bad month number\n");
        days = 0;
        break;
    }

    if ( days != 0 )
    printf ("Number of days is %i\n", days);

    if ( aMonth == february )
    printf ("...or 29 if it's a leap year\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This code is from a book I'm reading.

How do I fix this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
scanf ("%u", &aMonth);
```

Comment: only works as long as no one compiles with `-fshort-enums`, which is enabled by default on some platforms

Comment: I agree with Christoph. Your code previously assumed that an enum was an int, now it assumes that it is an unsigned, but both assumptions are unstable and non-portable. You should sscanf into an int or unsigned, range check, then assign to the enum.

Comment: @BruceDawson please put a finger in the ground and don't misuse the downvoting system. Look at the level of the problem and match the answer - you don't have to learn people about range checks, etc. in this context. Weird behaviour :S

Answer (score 4):

The `%i` conversion specification used with the `scanf` function matches a pointer to a signed integer. In C, an enumerated type is an implementation defined integer type compatible with that type.

In `gcc`, enums are normally of type `unsigned int` and of type `int` if there is a negative value in the enum constants.

See `gcc` implementation defined documentation on enums (emphasis mine):

> *The integer type compatible with each enumerated type (C90 6.5.2.2, C99 6.7.2.2).*
>
> Normally, the type is **unsigned int** if there are no negative values in the enumeration, otherwise int. If -fshort-enums is specified, then if there are negative values it is the first of signed char, short and int that can represent all the values, otherwise it is the first of unsigned char, unsigned short and unsigned int that can represent all the values.
>   On some targets, -fshort-enums is the default; this is determined by the ABI.

Source http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit_002dfields-implementation.html

To fix the warning on your system, just use the `%u` conversion specification that matches a pointer to an unsigned integer type:

```
scanf ("%u", &aMonth);
```

Comment: "In gcc, enums are normally of type unsigned int" - so your code will "normally" work on gcc. But not always. Downvoted because we can do better than "normally" working.

Answer (score 2):

Input an `int`, than assign it to the `enum month` object

```
int temp;
scanf("%d", &temp);
/* make sure 1 <= temp <= 12 */
aMonth = temp;
```

<s>Or you can try a cast, but it is not safe (*the representation of the `enum` and `int`s need not be the same*)</s>

```
scanf("%d", (int*)&aMonth);
```

*Note: the format specifier `"%i"` accepts values in decimal, hexadecimal, and octal notations.*

Answer (score 2):

The type underlying a particular enumeration isn't necessarily `int` - implementations are free to choose a smaller type as long as all values fit (gcc will do this if you enable `-fshort-enums`).

For a portable solution, make `aMonth` an `int` (any other integer type will do as long as you use the correct conversion specifier) and cast to `enum month` as necessary.